# I can't open a jira bug from Crashlytics anymore

Tags: jira, crashlytics

Since last week when I open an issue in Crashlytics (firebase) I can't find the button to open the Jira bug. It was previously in the right top corner, But now I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this has been submitted, and should have taken effect as of yesterday. Let me know if you're still having issues.